# Convert from getElementById to useRef in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-ref

There is a functional component implemented with getElementById and it needs to be updated to use useRef hook.

Original code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom';

const MyComponent: React.FunctionComponent<MyComponentProps> = ({
  myDefaultElement = 'default-element',
}) => {
  const [elementOutlet, setElementOutlet] = useState<HTMLOListElement>();

  useEffect(() => {
    const refElement = document.getElementById(myDefaultElement) as HTMLOListElement;
 
    if (refElement) {
      setElementOutlet(refElement);
    }
  }, [myDefaultElement]);

  return createPortal(
    <li>
     // something
    </li>,
    elementOutlet
  );
};
```

the above code works fine, the only change that I made was the first line inside useEffect.

From:

```
const refElement = document.getElementById(myDefaultElement) as HTMLOListElement;
```

To:

```
const refElement = useRef(myDefaultElement) as HTMLOListElement;
```

When hover the new line it says:

> React Hook "useRef" cannot be called inside a callback.  React Hooks
> must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook
> function

Is there a way to make ref work fine inside useEffect?

Answer (score 3):

You can't call `useRef` inside an effect, check the [rule of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). Try something like this

```
const Component = () =>{
  const node = useRef(null)
  useEffect(() =>{
    // current will never be null here, since this effect will 
    // only run after the first mount and therefore after refs 
    // appending
    setElementOutlet(node.current)
  },[])

  return <div ref={node} />
}
```

Refs already have an stable signature ensured by react's life cycle, so you don't have to declare it as a dependency inside your effect.

---

Judging by your example you're only receiving an `id` as props not the node itself. You have two options:

- Continue to receive the element id and calling `getElementById` (there is nothing wrong with that) and then append the mounted node inside a ref

```
const Component = ({ id }) =>{
  const node = useRef(document.getElementById(id))

  useEffect(() =>{
    const el = document.getElementById(id)
    if(el) node.current = el
  },[id])
}
```

- Receive the entire ref as props

```
const ParentComponent = () =>{
  const node = useRef(null)
  return(
    <>
      <Component childRef={node} />
      <div ref={node} />
    </> 
  )
}

const Component = ({ childRef }) =>{
 ...
}
```

Greetings fellow olister.

Comment: I don't get the return part. Are you sure this will work?

Comment: The element contained inside `current` is inside your component or coming via `props`?

Comment: maybe your answer is correct but as long as I cannot make it work in my case I cannot accept it. I've tried your second approach without success. The first approach isn't fine as it should use getElementById. thanks for your help

Comment: Could you provide a more detailed example? Maybe in codesandbox?

Comment: `current` property is read-only